# Significance of, and relation between: (1) the Fundamental Theorem of Finitely Generated Abelian Groups and (2) Free Abelian Groups

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, free-abelian-group

I'm trying to get the 'big picture' of when each of these might come in handy.

So far, it seems that we would prefer to be able to use the Fundamental Theorem of Finitely Generated Abelian Groups (FtFAG) whenever possible since this provides more information on how to **break up the structure of $G$ into simpler groups** that we can handle. This is obviously only available to us when $G$ is finitely generated.

If, however, $G$ is not finitely generated, we could turn to using Free Abelian Groups in order to understand something (likely less informative compared to what FtFAG would have been able to provide) about $G$'s structure. This, for example, would be made possible by defining a homomorphism $h$ between a free abelian group $F$ with infinite basis (of same cardinality as some generating set for $G$?) and then investigating the group $F/ker(h)$ (after applying the first isomorphism theorem, which is possible since $h$ is surjective). The idea is that $F$, $ker(h)$ provide more information to work with (two groups) compared to $G$ (one group), thus providing ***some* form of 'breaking up' $G$ into simpler groups**, as in FtFAG.

Would this intuition be correct? (if I had to sum it up -- would prefer to use FtFAG, but if cannot, turn to use free abelian groups?).

Is there anything else worth noting along these lines?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're describing in the paragraph about free abelian groups. The isomorphism you give is just a presentation of $G$ (albeit one that already factors through a free abelian group rather than a free (nonabelian) group), and it's effectively the structure of $G$ as it stands. Consider what the map would look like for non-fg groups like $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$, for example.

Comment: @anomaly I'm not sure yet what the map in your last sentence would look like, but in any case, it seems that it would still be sometimes useful to investigate $G$ via the quotient group, thus still providing a (little) more information (via two groups) on $G$ than if we had just taken $G$ as is. Is that not a valid case in favour of using free abelian groups to investigate non-fg groups?

Comment: Sure, but I'm not sure what you're actually going to get out of it. One common setup in abelian group theory is the (Prufer) rank of an abelian group $G$, which is the largest rank of free abelian subgroups of $G$. But even then it's not much of a decomposition or classification. The rank $0$ case covers every torsion group, so it contains complicated groups like $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$. The rank $1$ case turns out to be classified by subgroups of prime numbers, and I'm not personally familiar with the higher-rank cases.

Comment: @anomaly Well, in Hatcher's Algebraic Topology (https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf), Example 2.40, he uses this 'breaking up into $F$,$ker(h)$' to show there's an isomorphism to a general abelian group $G$ that is non-fg. So that's at least one use-case where the added information came in handy. Otherwise, what is the use of free abelian groups? (I'm genuinely asking - why are they of interest? Being the largest abelian group generated by some basis intuitively means that they can 'cover' (via surjective homomorphism) any abelian group, thus helping to describe it - no?).

Comment: Sure, but you could same about arbitrary free groups. I'm not sure what kind of answer you're looking for besides general (non-fg) abelian group theory (or maybe some homological algebra, but I'm mostly familiar with that in the context of algebraic topology). Take a look at the Whitehead problem, for example.